# Web3j fails to deploy simple Vyper Contract to Ganache

Tags: ganache, web3j, vyper

I have a simple *hello world* contract, compiled with Vyper.  I use Web3j CLI to make a Java wrapper class from the contract's abi and bin files. When I deploy it, I get a `stack underflow` error.

- I know the Vyper contract works, because I successfully deployed it with Truffle.
- I know my Web3j project is okay, because it can successfully deploy a Solidity *hello world* contract.

**QUESTION: Why won't Web3j deploy a simple Vyper contract?**

---

The Ganache Error:
`{"error":"stack underflow","program_counter":1,"return":"0x"}`

Vyper compile commands:

```
vyper -f abi -o hello.abi hello.vy
vyper -f bytecode -o hello.bin hello.vy
```

Versions:

- Ganache CLI v6.12.2 (ganache-core: 2.13.2)
- Web3j 4.9.6
- Vyper 0.3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My *Vyper* contract caused a *Ganache* error, because the `vyper` compiler formats its `bytecode` output with a `0x` prefix and a `\n` suffix.

`web3j-cli` takes that string *as is* and puts it into a contract Java wrapper class.  When `ganache-cli` receives that binary string, it throws a "*stack underflow*" error.

After stripping off the unwanted chars, the contract deploys successfully.

As of Feb. 2022, *Web3j* doesn't officially support contracts compiled from *Vyper*.  But you can make it work, as I explained.

When `solcjs` outputs a contract's binary, it *does not* add `0x` or `\n`.